Serial Commands for Mettler-Toledo FiveEasy Plus pH meter
I am trying to create an automated setup for measuring pH values of solutions. As part of this, I will interface with a Mettler-Toledo FiveEasy Plus pH meter using a RS232-USB cable connected to my PC. However, there is no documentation that I can find regarding commands that will make the meter measure the pH.
I have tried:
Contacting Mettler-Toledo. They say to use their (non-free) software, and that they won't help.
Performing a brute force scan. I wrote a function (not included below) that iterates through AAB, (where A is A-Z and B is 0-9), sending these messages through my function T() and listens for any response. This search yielded responses from "I2", "I3", "I4", "YM", "YS". The first 3 provide information about the machine (model number etc.), and the last 2 change the mode of the pH meter (I think).
Pressing the measure button. Using my autoprint() function, which sets a loop of listening for a response and printing, I can read off the pH from pressing the measure button on the pH meter. However, this defeats the purpose of an automated setup!
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('COM9',
        baudrate=1200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        #xonxoff=True,
        timeout = 0.2)
        print ("Connected to meter")
    except Exception as metererror:
        print("Unable to connect to meter:\n", metererror)


def autoprint(): # This works as expected when the measure button is pressed
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()
    weight = 0
    sleep(0.1)
    
    while "i" in "Hi":
        x = ser.readline()
        print (str(x))


def T(msg): # This will get outputs for the messages "I2", "I3", "I4", "YM", "YS"
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()
    sleep(0.1)

    msg = f"{msg}\r\n"
    msg = msg.encode('ascii')
    ser.write(msg)
    
    sleep(0.1)
    returnMsg = ser.readline()
    return (returnMsg)

The key differentiator between my question and other questions is that I am trying to trigger the measurement using serial commands - reading the pH meter's replies is not (as far as I can tell) an issue.
Has anyone had any success at getting their (Mettler-Toledo) pH probes to measure values over the serial interface? I have found serial commands for their balances online, and they seem to be relatively logical ("W" for weigh etc.), but I cannot find any serial documentation for their pH probes.
Or is there any particular namespace that I should be looking in with brute forcing/any tips for performing this search?

According to https://support.waters.com/KB_Inf/NuGenesis/WKB48889_How_do_I_connect_a_Mettler_Toledo_SevenExcellence_pH_meter_to_Waters_SDS the measure command might be "R". Does this work?

Thanks for the response! I don't think that it does work, as the first thing that I did was to iterate through all characters and got no response. This is assuming that "R\r\n" is how it is meant to be sent, other commands worked in this format (like "I2\r\n"). I think that this could be because this is for a different model (SevenExcellence instead of FiveEasy) and I believe that they have quite different control methods.
